# Access string value from try catch block

Tags: android, string, try-catch, parameter-passing

I am calling a method in OnCreate as following

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    GetScore();
```

The method is defined here

```
    private void GetScore() {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("email", textEmail);
    client.get("http://techcube.pk/game/getScore.php", params, new `enter code here`AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                super.onSuccess("Success");
                String  score = null;
                try
                {
                    Log.d("Success", s);
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
                     score = json.getString("Score");


                }


                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), score, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fetchlivescore.setText(score);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(throwable);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Response for onFailure ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

}
```

Now what i want to do is that i store the value of json string in fetchlivescore textview inside onSuccess method
but i want to use this value also on the Oncreate method i.e. when i open the app next time it show a toast or a textview containing the same value that was stored in the Onsuccess method.
how can i achieve this? i have tried many things but nothing works because the stored value is not showing next time in oncreate method and it always show empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to save the score would be to use SharedPreferences in your `onSuccess()` method.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("key_score", score);
editor.commit();
```

And in `onCreate()` you just read the value stored.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String score = sharedPref.getString("key_score");
```

If you're inside an Activity - use `this` instead of `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `SharedPreferences`. It's a key - value stored and the contents are persisted over app restarts.

Comment: I think i wasnt able to explain the problem completely

Comment: the problem is that i cannot access this value i.e fetchlivescore textview value outside this method why?

Comment: @ArslanAli How do you declare the `fetchlivescore` field?

Comment: it is also declared in the onCreate Method and iam setting it here in onSuccess

Comment: @ArslanAli Can you update your code listing to include it? If you declare it as a variable, you should pass it as a final param to the `GetScore` method to be able to use it. If you declare it as a field of your enclosing class, you should be able to use it with the current code you have.

Comment: I have tried shared preference and it works Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to store that value somewhere if you want to have it for later.
If it is just single value, maybe SharedPreferences are solution:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences...", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("score", score);
editor.commit();
```

And in onResume you can set your TextView with something like:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences...", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
textView.setText(prefs.getString("score",""));
```